# Order by last row of SELECT subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables: "posts" - for posts that a user post, and all the information it includes. and "messages" - which includes messages for each post.
The tables look like this:

**posts:**

```
--------------------------------------------------
| post_id | post_creator_id  | post_information  |
--------------------------------------------------
```

**messages:**

```
----------------------------------------------------------
| message_id |  post_id | user_id |     message_text     |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to display a user (user_id) a list of all chats he is engaged in, and order it by the last message sent in any chat.

So there are a few things to be done: first I need to group by the post_id in `messages` table (so there aren't duplicates) and order by `message_id` DESC, I tried subquery and joins but neither worked. Here is an example of my subquery attempt:

```
SELECT posts.post_information FROM posts WHERE posts.post_id in (SELECT 
 messages.post_id FROM messages ORDER BY message_id DESC)
```

Can't figure out how make the query display only distinct rows (without duplication of post_id) And whether join is a better option?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  And why does part of the question talk about ordering the messages, and another part talk about displaying only distinct rows.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking here.  Show clear and concise input data and the exact output you expect.  Otherwise, we would all be guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple change in your query, we can use `INNER JOIN` with `messages` table and `ORDER BY` with `message_id` instead of using suqbyery (It seems that you want to order output data by `message_id` in `descending` order.

```
SELECT posts.post_information 
FROM posts 
INNER JOIN (SELECT post_id, max(message_id) mid 
            FROM messages 
            GROUP BY post_id) mes ON mes.post_id = posts.post_id
ORDER BY mes.mid DESC
```

Comment: It is nearly working. The problem is that it gives you duplicates from messages. I need only 1 row for each unique post_id

Comment: Please try the new query posted above in TRY THIS

Comment: ok, but if the question is logically different then you can as a new question and leave it as it is.

Comment: I just realized that I also need the message_text, and when I try with PHP to fetch it I get "undefined index: message_text" , how can I also add that column? I tried to add "message_text" to the second select but that didn't work

Comment: Do you want to select `message_text` of each `post` based on `max(message_id)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have multiple messages per post, you need to use `distinct` not to include duplicates. Than just join tables and add `order by`

```
SELECT distinct posts.post_information 
FROM posts, messages where messages.post_id = posts.post_id
ORDER BY messages.message_id DESC
```

Comment: It does give list of distinct rows, but in my testings, when I add new message, the order remains the same (I think it only chooses the first row instead of last thus not changing order?)